# mysql encoding to allow emoji

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

In my `pipeline.py`

```
self.conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='usr154', password=PASSWORD, db='db_v1',
                                    charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
# Table exists with all column types to "text"
my_id="a13cg"
title='hello world'
my_string = 'Top 10 Ist es ein Cityhotel? Ist es ein Schloss? Ist es ein Inselresort? '
self.cursor.execute("""insert into results values (%s,%s,%s)""",(my_id,title,my_string))


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 154, in f
    return deferred_from_coro(coro_f(*coro_args, **coro_kwargs))
  File "/home/timmy/t_roman/t_roman/pipelines.py", line 44, in process_item
    self.cursor.execute("""insert into results values (%s,%s,%s)""",
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x94\\x8D' for column 'htmlSnippet' at row 1")
```

I tried encoding the value but it didn't work as well

```
my_string = my_string.encode()
```

Hello, I have the following pipeline which fills up MySQL which is used (eventually) in a flask app, How can I correctly store those values so later on I can display them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert to bytes ( I assume this is scrapy MySQL pipeline),since the table is already created you can use it like this.

```
self.cursor.execute("""ALTER TABLE results CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin""")
```

you can also change the column type from `text` to `NVARCHAR(255)`

[The binary Collation Compared to _bin Collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-binary-collations.html)

Answer (score -1):

The problem with this is that you're using bytes to encode a string when my_string is not a string.  Emojis can be used as strings by sending them as unicode. Each emoji has a corresponding unicode string assigned to it.  For example:

```
# grinning face 
print("\U0001f600") 

# grinning squinting face 
print("\U0001F606") 

# rolling on the floor laughing 
print("\U0001F923")
```

Comment: you mean I need to convert my strings to Unicode then store them?

Comment: @goku I believe that should work.  The pipeline isn't recognizing the emojicons because the first bytes tell the program what kind of data is in the bytes.  If you use Unicode the bytes should be recognized as a string and go through